# JDBC Connection issue on embedded tomcat

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

In my spring boot application, i am creating a datasource using org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource. I am using embedded tomcat. Below are some of the properties i have set

```
myDS.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
myDS.setUrl(databaseURL);
myDS.setUsername(databaseUserId);
myDS.setTestWhileIdle(false);
myDS.setTestOnBorrow(true);
myDS.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
myDS.setTestOnReturn(false);
myDS.setValidationInterval(30000);
myDS.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
myDS.setMaxActive(100);
myDS.setInitialSize(10);
myDS.setMaxWait(10000);
myDS.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
myDS.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
myDS.setMinIdle(10);
myDS.setLogAbandoned(true);
myDS.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
```

I am using this ds object in two spring beans which have scope as prototype. When i use first functionality which uses first spring bean application works fine. Then i hit second funcationality which uses same ds object then i get below error

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.
```

Internally in my code i am using jdbcTemplate for db operations. I tried using destroy method but it did not work

@Bean(destroyMethod="")
public DataSource appDS(){

Please suggest

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: why aren't you using the `spring.datasource` namespace. It does all of that automatically.

Comment: I changed the verification query and it started working fine. My question is why do i get this error on embedded tomcat and why not on external or standalone tomcat

Comment: I am using DB2 database, changed the validation query to SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i am using DB2 database, i changed the validation query as follows and it started working

SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1

Note - Embedded Tomcat and Standalone tomcat behavior is different for same configurations. On Standalone tomcat, you do not get exception for invalid validation query. External tomcat version 7